# Регистрация/Авторизация

Tags: php

Подскажите как сделать чтобы когда пользователь заполнил поля регистрации/авторизации и в случае ошибки при обновлении странички введенные поля не опустошались.

Пример кода:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        $title = "Регистрация";
        require_once "blocks/head.php";
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once "blocks/header.php" ?>       

<div class="block_for_messages">
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION["error_messages"]) && !empty($_SESSION["error_messages"])){
            echo $_SESSION["error_messages"];
            unset($_SESSION["error_messages"]);
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION["success_messages"]) && !empty($_SESSION["success_messages"])){
            echo $_SESSION["success_messages"];
            unset($_SESSION["success_messages"]);
        }
    ?>
</div>

<?php
    //Проверяем, если пользователь не авторизован, то выводим форму регистрации, 
    //иначе выводим сообщение о том, что он уже зарегистрирован
    if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]) && !isset($_SESSION["password"])){
?>

    <form action="register.php" method="post" name="signup">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="regy">
                <h1 align="center">tAKNYT</h1>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Имя и Фамилия" required="required" name="fullName" ><br />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Имя пользователя" required="required" name="username"><br />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="required" name="email"><br />
                <span id="svalid_email_message" class="mesage_error"></span>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" id="password" name="password"><br />
                <span id="svalid_password_message" class="mesage_error"></span>
                <div id="pacl">
                        <input type="submit" name="btn_submit_register" value="Зарегистрироваться!">
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>  
    </form>
<?php
    }else{
?>      
    <div id="authorized">
        <h2>Вы уже зарегестрированы</h2>
    </div>  
<?php   
    }
    require_once "blocks/footer.php" 
?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Так же как вы ошибки выводите через сессии, если ошибка в форме и нужно вернуть пользователя на форму - пишите то что он заполнил в сессии, потом после перезагрузки страницы отображаете данные из сессии и чистите эти данные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сперва запоминаешь в сессии значения с формы, а когда выводишь форму в тэг value формы подставляешь эти значения. После этого удаляешь эти переменные из сессии.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {
    $_SESSION["oldFullName"] = $_POST["fullName"];
};
?>

<form action="register.php" method="post" name="signup">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Имя и Фамилия" required="required" 
    name="fullName" value="<?php echo  $_SESSION["oldFullName"] ?>"
</form>
<?php
    unset($_SESSION["oldFullName"]);
?>
```